# Remote Access/Editing files from Android without rooting on any other remote platform

Tags: nexus-7, files, remote-access

I have a Nexus 7 Tablet and a Samsung Galaxy Ace Phone. I wish to use WiFi only. The phone does not have a 3G tariff.

As the Nexus 7 Tablet does not have an SD card slot of any type, I wish to find a way to connect the Nexus 7 Tablet to other devices including the Samsung Galaxy ACE phone or any other form of inexpensive external storage while mobile, and Windows/Linux PC's when at home.

More specifically I wish to access files stored remotely, to edit the files, and save them remotely, without writing the file to the Nexus 7 local storage at any point from opening to saving and closing, and using any application on the Nexus 7, such as a Word Processor/Spreadsheet.

I wish to accomplish this without rooting either the Tablet or the Phone. I am concerned that rooting will compromise what little security is built into Android. My concern stems from the fact that there is little guarantee that some applications will not accidentally or deliberately take advantage of the device once rooted.

I am aware of applications such as ES File Explorer, and would choose to use such an app, if I could connect it to another Android Device, perhaps if there were a Samba/CIFS server which could use custom ports (>1024) as long as I could also use the same ports on ES File Explorer (or similar app) either through the config of the apps themselves or by some mechanism to reroute ports as may be found in a Home Firewall Router.

I would also be open to using SSH as a means of facilitating a connection if necessary.

I do not wish to use Cloud Services as I do not trust that the Operator will not copy, use, or lose any data I upload.

Comment: "My concern stems from the fact that there is little guarantee that some applications will not accidentally or deliberately take advantage of the device once rooted." Rooting the device doesn't mean that every app has root: it means you can choose. Only an app you choose to give root access has the opportunity to exploit it.

Comment: *if I could connect it to another Android Device, perhaps if there were a Samba/CIFS server which could use custom ports (>1024)* Have you checked the play store for those? Most Samba servers will require root, but if you can live with the "custom ports", there's e.g. [Samba Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sambaserver) not requiring root.

Comment: Would FTP be acceptable solution?  It does mean writing the file locally though, but seems like the easiest direction without rooting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the part rendering solutions close to imposible is *without writing the file to the Nexus 7 local storage at any point from opening to saving and closing*. If that should also exclude automatically created temp files, you're very much out of luck.

Additionally: *and using any application on the Nexus 7* Yo. That means either all apps have to support Samba/CIFS/whatever network protocol to be used – or you need to mount that network drive locally. This brings it down to apps like [CifsManager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/CifsManager/ws.plattner.cifsmanager) (last release: 4/2011) or [Mount Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Mount-Manager/com.twimager.cifsmanager) (requires root; I would wonder if that doesn't apply to CifsManager as well). Moreover, on your remote device you will need the counterpart providing the network drive, of course. No problem on the PC, where it comes with the OS. For your other Android device, as pointed out in my comment on your question, that could e.g. be [Samba Server](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.icecoldapps.sambaserver).

Answer (score 0):

You may use software like [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.ftpserver&hl=it) to let someone read and write your files on your device remotely via FTP, and ES or similar software to access to. Note though that you'll still need to download the file, in order to modify it.

The simpliest solution may be to run an SSH server on your target device and then accessing it via a terminal emulator: in this way, you'll be able to edit your text files without the need of downloading it (using nano or similar software, installed on the target device).